# What WYSIWYG editing component should I use for in-browser editing?

Tags: browser, editor, cross-browser, wysiwyg, richtextediting

I'm looking for a good, WYSIWYG editor that I can integrate into my web pages enabling my users to edit letters, legal agreements, etc. without requiring them to learn a new set of commands or syntax or going crazy trying to remove a table or resize an image.

I have read the relate questions. And I have used probably most of the better ones, including fckeditor, tinymce, and ephox. And have looked at many others. None are what I consider a really *good* editor.

Ephox was the best one in terms of editing. But it's a heavy java applet. The ideal solution would be JavaScript-based. I am aware that the browser is the limiting factor and it will probably take one or more generations to get to where I want.

Any suggestions? Anything new coming into the market?

Comment: shouldn't this be on superuser? i hear it's come out of beta finally

Comment: Why would it be on superuser? This is very much programming related.

Comment: I could see it being subjective, but the question was asked in a very neutral fashion so I don't think it is Subjective **and** Argumentative. It is asking about a code editor recomendation so definitely appropriate for SO.

Comment: Please define "best".  Smallest?  Most features?  Best license terms?  Easiest to extend?

Comment: Since it is clearly a subjective question, each answerer would be free to use there own definition of best.

Comment: Ok, this is pointless. *Artilheiro*, obviously you have some specific needs and a strong opinion as to how they should be met - so use those needs and opinions to inform your question, don't ask for a subjective "best" and *then* try to limit the inevitably subjective responses. I've taken a stab at rewording your question to reflect where you appear to be headed - please add in some more details as to what sort of behavior you need and why the components you've tried so far do or do not satisfy you.

Comment: I agree that there is no way that we can tell the OP what the best solution for them is. What we can do is give some suggestions that the OP (and future readers) can try. I don't like these sorts of questions on SO, but since the OP did a relatively good job of making it non-argumentative I didn't vote to close. I would say just go ahead and answer what you want ignoring the OP limitation and explain the good points of your answer.

Comment: oh come on why close this? ask the OP to be a little more clear, but don't just close their question, its not that bad :D

Comment: Eh, this is why it's a good idea for authors to check back now and then after asking a question...

Answer (score 2):

If you want something more language agnostic use fckEditor  http://www.fckeditor.net/

Answer (score 1):

After much experimenting, I've settled on [ckeditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/). Good standards-support in output code, pretty easy implementation, jQuery integration, fully featured, very customisable, and not forgetting the winning feature: cleaning of [pasted Word crap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379342/php-to-clean-up-pasted-microsoft-input).

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo rich text editor:
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/

Comment: last time I looked they were missing some needed functionality such as Tables and HTML code.

Comment: good to know, thanks.  I currently use fckeditor, but was planning on giving the RTE a shot on my next project.

Comment: Linked-to page is gone.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents: Just used **tinyMce** with two projects:

- simple theme: small size, server side compresor/builder, jQuery engine integration
- advance theme - nice file upload, image library with image crop and resize
- can be used as an jQuery plugin, very aproachable

About your thoughts about advance editing - I dont think they will be possible. If they become available, they are probably going to be browser specific or will have large codebase and a different feel - [mozilla bespin](http://bespin.mozilla.com) (not wysiwyg - jet)

Comment: Yes, I like tinyMCE too. Although, it sorta breaks down for big documents with lots of formatting. For me as a user it would be fine because if I get stuck I can always fix the HTML and move on. But our users had a lot trouble with it which turned into a lot of support cases for the company. We still use for smaller fields such as formatted comments and emails. Now we are using Ephox for mail merge documents.

Comment: jQuery + tinyMCE... that's an excellent idea for the where we use tinyMCE, since we already use both. Thanks for the pointer

Comment: I am taking a look at bespin. Thanks for that also.

Answer (score 0):

We use CuteEditor from http://cutesoft.net/ASP.NET+WYSIWYG+Editor/ and highly recommend it.