# Remove the unwanted commented code copied from word using php

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP to clean-up pasted Microsoft input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379342/php-to-clean-up-pasted-microsoft-input)

Need to remove the code in comments

```
[if gte mso 9]><xml> <w:WordDocument>  ..... --> [endif] -->
```

from my db field, when copying text from word and saving this unwanted code is coming.In Ie the source after this was not displaying as it causes display problems

Comment: More info please. Where does the Word data get pasted into? A rich text editor? Does that editor have the option to strip Word markup info?

Comment: the word data get pasted into fck editor using tiny mice

Answer (score 0):

If thats the exact string you would like to clean then you can use something like this

```
 $clean_string = preg_replace("/(\[if.+?\[endif\]\s{0,}-->)/","",$dirty_string);
```

Example here

http://ideone.com/cf0MG

Updated ideone link
http://ideone.com/08L6L

Comment: fails in the presence of multiple "comments" in the input string, since .* is greedy and will race to the end of the string, then back up only enough to match. (to the last [endif]). Also, *  means 'zero or more' too, and is little more readable than {0,}.

Comment: ahh sorry should be +? editing now thanks for pointing it out, and yeah I agree with putting a * there :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$clean_string = preg_replace("/(\[if\s.*?\].*?\[endif\]\s*-->/)","",$dirty_string);
```

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at the [paste](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3apaste) plugin:

> [paste_remove_styles] If true, removes all style information when pasting, regardless of browser type. Pasting from Word 2000 will cause tinyMCE to error. Default is false.