# php regular expression removing mso tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this html code :

```
$html = "<P style="mso-margin-top-alt: auto; mso-margin-bottom-alt: auto; padding: 4px;" class=MsoNormal>text</P>";
```

I need to remove all mso-* tag, and the result will be:

```
$html = "<P style="padding: 4px;" class=MsoNormal>text</P>";
```

How can I do with php??
Many Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP to clean-up pasted Microsoft input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379342/php-to-clean-up-pasted-microsoft-input)

Comment: @Pekka not a good dup imo. It basically just says use HTMLPurifier or Tidy and there is just one answer altogether.

Comment: @Gordon I guess it depends on what the OP really wants. If he wants to clean up *all* the Microsoft stuff, HTMLPurifier is indeed the best method I know. If he wants to do *exactly* what he shows above (and nothing more), it's different.

Comment: @Ste can you please clarify what you are after: cleaning this particular snippet or cleaning all the Microsoft stuff altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code :**

```
$html = "<p style='mso-margin-top-alt: auto; mso-margin-bottom-alt: auto; padding: 4px;' class=MsoNormal>text</P>";

$cleanHtml = preg_replace('(mso-[a-z\-: ]+; )i', '', $html);

echo $cleanHtml;
```

**Output :**

```
<P style='padding: 4px;' class=MsoNormal>text</P>
```

Comment: This is a valid regex solution. Although I'd use `~` or `/` as regex delimiters and put `-` at the end of the character class to avoid overescaping: `preg_replace('~mso-[a-z: -]+; ~i', '', $html)`.

Answer (score 3):

This would work:

```
echo preg_replace(
    '(
        mso-   # match anything with the mso vendor prefix
        .+?    # followed by at least one character
        ;      # up to the first semicolon
        [ ]*   # and an optional space
    )xi',
    '',        // replace that match with nothing
    $html
);
```

However, in case there is more that just that one line of html in `$html`, have a look at [Grabbing the href attribute of an a element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/regular-expression-for-grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element/3820783#3820783) to learn how to easily and reliably fetch attributes from elements in html. Then use above regex to replace the node values.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one;

```
(mso-[^:]*:[^;]*;)
```

*However, do not forget to not to parse html with regex, it's a really big sin!*

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/mso-.+?:\s*?.+?;/s', '', $html);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = '<P style="mso-margin-top-alt: auto; mso-margin-bottom-alt: auto; padding: 4px;" class=MsoNormal>text</P>';
$patterns = '/mso-(.*?);/';
$replacements = '';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the solution of Dr.Kameleon: it works fine but it doesn't work for all situation. For example for the following code, mso-* attributes will not remove:

```
<p style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto' class=MsoNormal>text</P>
```

(I delete some spaces and ";").

So, I suggest you some improvements of the code of Dr.Kameleon:

```
$cleanHtml = preg_replace('(mso-[a-z0-9\s\-:;]+)i', '', $html);
```

Best regard