# PHP Preg_replace MS Word Image Tags only

Tags: php, html, ms-word

I have a customer who generates his newsletters in word, then copies the HTML into MailChimp to send out.
Word has all of its strange and wonderful formatting ideas, most of which I need to keep so the formatting is consistent to what he is used too, and what he see's in word.

The only real issue is how MS Word inserts Images, here is a snippit, it add's both a <img> tag, and  a <v:shape><v:imagedata> tag:

```
<td width=640 style='width:480.0pt;border-top:solid #1F497D 1.0pt;mso-border-top-themecolor: text2;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid #1F497D 1.0pt;mso-border-bottom-themecolor: text2;border-right:none;background:#1F497D;mso-background-themecolor:text2; padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;height:26.6pt'>
<p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center'><b style='mso-bidi-font-weight:normal'><span style='font-family:"Arial","sans-serif"; mso-ansi-language:EN-NZ;mso-fareast-language:EN-NZ;mso-no-proof:yes'><!--[if gte vml 1]><v:shapetype id="_x0000_t75" coordsize="21600,21600" o:spt="75" o:preferrelative="t" path="m@4@5l@4@11@9@11@9@5xe" filled="f" stroked="f">
<v:stroke joinstyle="miter"/>
<v:formulas>
<v:f eqn="if lineDrawn pixelLineWidth 0"/>
<v:f eqn="sum @0 1 0"/>
<v:f eqn="sum 0 0 @1"/>
<v:f eqn="prod @2 1 2"/>
<v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelWidth"/>
<v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelHeight"/>
<v:f eqn="sum @0 0 1"/>
<v:f eqn="prod @6 1 2"/>
<v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelWidth"/>
<v:f eqn="sum @8 21600 0"/>
<v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelHeight"/>
<v:f eqn="sum @10 21600 0"/>
</v:formulas>
<v:path o:extrusionok="f" gradientshapeok="t" o:connecttype="rect"/>
<o:lock v:ext="edit" aspectratio="t"/>
</v:shapetype><v:shape id="_x0000_i1033" type="#_x0000_t75" style='width:479.25pt;height:112.5pt;visibility:visible;mso-wrap-style:square'>
<v:imagedata src="22nd%20September%20-%20Take%205...%20Your%205%20minute%20fortnightly%20roundup%20of%20alcohol%20and%20other%20drug%20news%20and%20research%202_files/image001.png" o:title=""/>
</v:shape><![endif]--><![if !vml]><img border=0 width=639 height=150 src="22nd%20September%20-%20Take%205...%20Your%205%20minute%20fortnightly%20roundup%20of%20alcohol%20and%20other%20drug%20news%20and%20research%202_files/image025.png"v:shapes="_x0000_i1033"><![endif]></span></b><b style='mso-bidi-font-weight:normal'><span lang=EN-GB style='font-family:"Arial","sans-serif"'><o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
```

If I strip all of the MS code it kills all of formatting:

```
$parsed_html = preg_replace('/<!--\[[\s\S]*?\]-->/s', '', $html);
```

I've tried to be more specific:

```
$parsed_html = preg_replace('/<!--\[if gte vml 1\]*?--><!\[if !vml\]>/s', '', $html);
```

But this is working okay, but again stripping too much. 
Do you know if there is a way in word to export better HTL ( haha ) or a better match pattern.

Here is a full word HTML doc: 
http://pastebin.com/myPwnHbd

Here is the PHP so far (Uploads the html file from a simple HTML form):
http://pastebin.com/Wc7hEk7c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400260/remove-ms-word-html-using-php

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, That thread points to :
http://htmlpurifier.org/

My final code (summarized) is:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(0); ini_set('display_errors', FALSE);

    require_once 'htmlpurifier-4.8.0/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

    $html = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

    $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();

    $config->set('Core.Encoding', 'ISO-8859-1');

    $config->set('AutoFormat.AutoParagraph', true);

    $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

    $clean_html = $purifier->purify( $html );

    echo $clean_html;
```