# remove html tag using regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match-all

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP to clean-up pasted Microsoft input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379342/php-to-clean-up-pasted-microsoft-input)

Hi help using regex or any php function that can remove

```
<o:p></o:p> or <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p> or <o:p> </o:p>
```

from my string

Example

```
<p class=MsoNormal>Category: Paul :asadad<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Car: Toyota <o:p> </o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Sports: Soccer<o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
```

I need it to be

```
<p class=MsoNormal>Category: Paul :asadad</p><p class=MsoNormal>Car: Toyota 1</p><p class=MsoNormal>Sports: Soccer</p>
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: So what regex have you managed so far?

Comment: if you just want to remove the elements, you can use `str_replace`. apart from that, there is plenty of answers showing how to remove elements with an XML parser on StackOverflow, so give it a search please.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+removeChild+[php]&submit=search

Comment: Hmmm do you have any idea if the FCKEditor cleanup script can be called by php without using JS. I think that would help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $str =  '<p class=MsoNormal>Category: Paul :asadad<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Vessel Name: Vessel 1<o:p> </o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Sub Category: asdasdad<o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>';
   $pattern = '#(<o:p>\s*[\&nbsp;]*\s*<\/o:p>)#';
   $str = preg_replace($pattern, '', $str);
   echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP, why don't you just use the [strip_tags() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)? I would give it a shot, you can even specify tags, you want to left in the text. See the link for more details.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider using strip_tags

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('#<o:p>(\s|&nbsp;)*</o:p>#', '', $text);
```