# Clean HTML from Word documents

Tags: php, html, mysql, doc

Ok, so my company has a client that has an interface for posting content - standard MySQL database, PHP-based, etc.

Anyway, they've continually had an intern or someone, post content to this interface straight from an MS Word doc - the interface is coded poorly, and takes this input as is, with no formatting.

My company has now been contracted out to fix this particular problem, as it is continually breaking their site, and my company has repeatedly had to manually go into the database, and delete the offending values.

Is there a quick and easy way to do this, or am I going to have to just do a replace operation on each offending character?

I see `htmlentities()` may be a partial solution - but as far as I know, that won't remove everything.

What's a good solution to this problem? Is there anything out there to make this easier?

We're also considering writing a content validator as well, probably just server-side (though maybe client-side, if my week is going slowly enough/I finish the rest of this quickly enough).

Comment: Solution? Fire, or otherwise 'educate,' the intern. Long term, and realistic, solution? Manual intervention and review.

Comment: Good luck! I've been involved in a similar situation. Real pain in the a$$

Comment: I don't know for sure it's an intern - hell, it could be the company CEO - maybe he's 65 or something. Was just a joke more or less.

There should be a way to code this sort of thing though, correct?

Comment: Basically, no. Whatever's done automatically tends to need ridiculous numbers of edge cases to be accounted for. And, ultimately, falls prey to the same issues as parsing with regex. The *only* (realistic) solution is explaining that the problem is self-inflicted and needlessly expensive to correct. Seriously: educate your clients.

Comment: Best to write your own function that strips out all MS Word metadata crap. Even if you use a WYSIWYG editor that has the option to do it for you, odds are they won't use the option any way. Been there before.

Comment: If you provide: sample of an offending document, current code for parsing/storing input and code for output formating, maybe someone could help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP to clean-up pasted Microsoft input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379342/php-to-clean-up-pasted-microsoft-input)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how many clients (or potential clients) you are supporting and how much time you have to invest. Options

- Write your own function to strip out the metadata
- Teach your clients to remove it themselves such as paste in notepad first,
  or supply a knowledge base article to explain how to do it in the software.  Perhaps a "Help" section or icon they can click on. 
  htttp://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;223396
- Use a WYSIWYG editor such as TinyMCE which has built in functionality to remove it

But like I said in the comments, unless you are using your own function, prepare for clients to continue to paste directly and wonder why there is a problem.